# How to create dynamic menus in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular9

I am trying to create dynamic, nested menus in Angular(9), following [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-nested-topnav-menu) link.

I don't know what is missing, getting below errors.

[image]

[image]

My code in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ueh1hy). TIA.

Comment: what you trying do here can explain more

Comment: @harkeshkumar I am trying to create dynamic menus using mentioned link, but unable to create..

Comment: @RazRonen can you please explain more, not getting you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is that `menu.childMenu`, which is `ViewChild`, is not initalized yet at the time of passing it to the `matMenuTriggerFor` directive.

Simple fix is to tell Angular to initialize it before `ngOnInit` by using `static: true` option in `@ViewChild` decorator:

```
@ViewChild('childMenu', { static: true }) public childMenu;
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4xebft?file=src/app/nested-menus/nested-menus.component.ts)**

Comment: thanks @yurzui, its working like a charm on stackblitz. Actually I have already tried it but had no luck. Wasted lots of time on this fix, thanks alot again. Just checking if its working in project as well, will let you know...